# $(document).ready but in IE document.body is still null

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, document, ready

This seems weird. In IE I'm waiting for $(document).ready(). Once document is ready, I console log document.body and it's null. If I wrap it in a timeout, it's there? Shouldn't document.body be good to go on document ready? for an example:

```
// doesn't work
$(x.document).ready( function() { 
  x.document.body.innerHTML = '<div style="background-color: 000; color: #FF0000  ;">Cyril Figgis</div>';
});


// works
$(x.document).ready( function() { 
  setTimeout( function() { 
    x.document.body.innerHTML = '<div style="background-color: #000; color: #FF0000  ;">Hello!</div>';
  }, 1000 );
} );
```

document.body is defined after a second, but not immediately?

Comment: x should be a variable representing `window`

Comment: yea, x represents window object, I just tried to remove extraneous code

Comment: I suspect your problem is with `x`.  Why you are using anything in front of `document`?  The normal way to specify that you want to wait for the current document to be ready is: `$(document).ready(fn)`.

Comment: I'm controlling another window/tab from the current window. Thus I use a function similar to window.open() and save back to x. That way I can $(x.document).ready()

Comment: actually it is just window.open()

Answer (score 0):

I'm just researching this as I'm running in the same issue on IE9, and I thought this 2-years old jQuery bug entry might be interesting: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12282

Citing from there: "In the example provided, you are relying on the async execution of .ready(), which isn't a gaurantee. This is because .ready() fires a bit earlier in 1.8 because it does a new check for DOM readiness."

Your code is similar to mine - we're assuming ready() will be executed asynch when the document is actually ready, but as the jQuery guy stated this might not always be the case.